# How to create a Java program in Beanshell PostProcessor in Jmeter to merge all the responses?

Tags: jmeter, response, export-to-csv, beanshell

I have to send JSON requests based on the CSV test data. Suppose there are 90 records - which are basically the request bodies. I put the Thread in a loop to keep sending the request until the last one in the CSV.
Every time I get the response, I need to append them into a single CSV file. Now, since Jmeter Listener does not consolidate all the responses into CSV (I do not want it in xml), I want to know if I can write a Java snippet in BeanShell, capture all responses and write them to a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with [File.append](https://code-maven.com/groovy-files)  adding text with `,` to append to CSV file

> This will append to the end of the file.
>
> ```
> File file = new File("out.txt")
> file.append("hello\n")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "program"

1. Add [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your Test Plan ([since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   new File('myfile.csv') << prev.getResponseDataAsString() << System.getProperty('line.separator')
   ```

   where **prev** stands for previous [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance. Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more information on [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements.

---

A better option would be saving a response into a JMeter Variable using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and writing it to a file via [sample_variables property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)